# TestLinkAPIException: User corresponding to Developer Key has insufficient rights to perform this action- Details

Tags: selenium, testlink

I want to update test-cases execution result from selenium to testlink server.

For fulfill this requirement, I performed following changes:

```
(1) Modified the config.inc.php file like this: 

/** XML-RPC API availability (disabled by default) */
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;

// ENABLED -> enable XML-RPC calls to external test automation server
// new buttons will be displayed on execution pages
// DISABLED -> disable
$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enable_test_automation = ENABLED;

(2) Created a user with admin rights and login to Testlink 
(3) Go to 'My Settings' Under API interface, click 'Generate new key'. Configured new generated key in java code for integrate selenium and testlink server.
```

After performed above changes I got following error during execution of test-cases from selenium.

```
FATAL: User corresponding to Developer Key has insufficient rights to perform this action- Details: right testplan_create_build, test project id: 1, test plan id: 436
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: User corresponding to Developer Key has insufficient rights to perform this action- Details: right testplan_create_build, test project id: 1, test plan id: 436
```

If you have any idea then please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked with testlink years ago but I have a suspicion. Testlink differentiated between global rights and global rights in thid time. So if you are "only" a project admin you could get this problem. I had similiar problems with the right concept while configuring the tool for us.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Please find attached screen-shots for my Testlink user details with all rights.

I don't know what should I do..

Please suggest me with description.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... is this configuration for the project or for whole testlink? I can't see any mistake. If I'm right, the global configuration should also look like this and you also have to have admin as global role. GUI changed immensely. If it isn't the global config I don't know where to go. Is there still the help file accessible in a list in the right upper corner?